# Closing newly opened JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I'm developing a desktop application using NetBeans IDE.

1) I'm opening a new JFrame after a button click. While I'm closing any of the opened frames, both are getting closed.

2) And I want to update a new Tabbed JPanel on a JFrame after button click. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably you are using the wrong argument. I guess for the JFrames that you want to close without closing the entire application you are doing:

```
jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

While to actually close only the desired frame without closing rest of the frames you need to do:

```
jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Its working,so i got a solution for my first question.Can you please help me for the second.

Comment: @sakthibalaji...Please post an SSCCE. From what I can guess, you need to add an `ActionListener` to the button and do the updating part in the `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: Technically, the OP was using the *right* method with the *wrong* argument.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

1) Why did you create lots of [Top-Level Containers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) on Runtime, create only one [JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) and other would be JDialog(Modality) or JWindow(un-decorated), re-use that,

2) really no battery included in my Magic Globe today, for better and sooner hepl you have to post here [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 3):

> I want to update a new `JTabbedPane` on a `JFrame` after the button click.

You can just update via a reference to the tab's `JPanel` and call `repaint()`, but sooner or later you should consider the [Model–View–Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066590/gui-problem-after-rewriting-to-mvc/3072979#3072979) pattern.